# Por que no leelemi lista (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, dataframe

Estoy tratando de crear un grafico y necesito leer unos dataframes con pandas, trate de crear una lista y un ciclo for, pero al tratar de leerla no reconce la variable. Sin embargo al introducir un numero funciona perfectamente, no se cual pueda ser el problema.

```
import pandas as pd

# Visualization Modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

%matplotlib inline
```

```
maxtok=df1[('Tokyo','Max. Temp. [degC]')]#maximum temperature in tokyo

df3=pd.DataFrame()

dic=['2018']
dic2=['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']
print(dic[0])

for i in range(12):
  df3[0+i]=maxtok['2018-%s'%(dic2[0+i])]
  print(dic2[i])
print(df3[11])
```

falla, pero

```
maxtok=df1[('Tokyo','Max. Temp. [degC]')]#maximum temperature in tokyo

df3=pd.DataFrame()

dic=['2018']
dic2=['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']
print(dic[0])

for i in range(12):
  df3[0+i]=maxtok['2018-%s'%(dic2[11])]
  print(dic2[i])
print(df3[11])
```

funciona perfectamente

Comment: ¿Dónde está la diferencia?

Comment: la diferencia esta en 
```
df3[0+i]=maxtok['2018-%s'%(dic2[11])]
```
en la primera es una variable y en la otra es un int (1,2,11)

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: Buen día, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema. Algunas filas de tu `dataframe`. También agrega una explicación de lo que deseas hacer porque yo creo qué tal vez con `loc` y `max` se puede hacer.